# Using a price index in a regression without causing endogeneity

Tags: regression, econometrics, endogeneity

I have the following situation:

I observe house prices $y_{(i,j)}$ where $i$ is the object and $j$ is the region (say a county). However, since prices for some regions $j$ are hardly observed I would like to add "meta" information to my regression by including an observed average price (from a different source) $p_j$ for each region $j$.

The first attempt of regressing:

$
y_{(i,j)} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \times x_1 + \ldots + \beta_k \times p_j + e
$

will lead to endogeneity issues (as far as I understand) since

$
p_j = \dfrac{\sum_i y_{i,j}}{n} 
$

(sorry for the sloppy notation). So here are my questions:

- Is the issue I brought up of any relevance for the regression?
- How to deal with situation. Is there a way of incorporating additional aggregate Information in my model without running into endogeneity issues?